# Run UDP server over and over again in background

Tags: swift, udp, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

In my Swift 2.2 app, I'm using UDP to communicate over the local network. I'm using SwiftSocket for sending and receiving UDP. Setting up a UDP server works like this with the library:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
        let server:UDPServer=UDPServer(addr:"192.168.1.9",port:8888)
        let run:Bool=true
        while run{
            let (data, _,_)=server.recv(1024)
            if let d=data{
                if let str=String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){

                    print(str)

                }
            }

            server.close()
            break

        }

    })
```

The dispatch_async is good because it can take hours to receive a message, and it won't freeze the app when you receive nothing like you would encounter if you use dispatch_sync.

The problem with this method: when one UDP packet is received, the server stops and this code isn't repeated. This code should be repeated whenever a packet is received.

If you use a while loop with dispatch_sync, it works fine but the app freezes. If you use a while loop with dispatch_async it will instantly run again and the memory will be full within seconds.
This may be a pretty dumb question, but some help would be great!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Err, open the UDP socket elsewhere and don't close it here?

Comment: You mean like remove server.close?